# How to change a border color of html select tag if value is empty or 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 `select` tag with class name `select2` assigned to it. I want to make the border turn to red if there's no selected options or has an value equal to empty or 0. I've tried to add class using jquery but it makes all `select.select2` border turns red.

### Style

```
<style>
    .errorType {
        border-color: #F00 !important;
    }
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<select name="category" class="form-control select2" id="category" onChange="search_Operator(this.value)">
  <option value="0"> Select Operator Category</option>
  <option value="1">one</option> <option value="2"> two</option>     
</select>
<select name="operatorName" class="form-control select2" id="operatorName" onChange="">
  <option value="0"> Select operator Name</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2"> two</option>
</select>
<select name="regionName" class="form-control select2" id="regionName">  
  <option value="0"> Select region Name</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2"> two</option>
</select>
<select name="type" class="form-control select2" id="type">
  <option value="0"> Select type </option>
</select>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
});

$(".select2-selection").addClass('errorType');
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean boarder a border?

Comment: Use id instead of a class for that

Comment: i have tried that but it is not working.

Comment: I don't really get the idea, If I understand it correctly, you are trying to, make the border red, when?

Comment: on submit button click if select element selected value=0 then apply the class errorType which is making the border red.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached a function to the click event of the submit button, in order to check the value of every select element on the page:

```
$(function () {

      $('.form-control-select2').select2();

      $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){

         var submit_form = true;

         $(".form-control-select2").each(function(){

             var selected_value = $(this).val();

             if (selected_value==0 || selected_value=='') {
                 $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').addClass('errorType');
                 submit_form = false;
             } else {
                $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').removeClass('errorType');
             }

        });

        return submit_form;

     });    

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/64a41thz/21/.

---

Also, if you want to remove the red border when valid selection is made, add the following code:

```
$('.form-control-select2').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()!=0 && $(this).val()!='') {
        $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').removeClass('errorType');
    }
 });
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/64a41thz/24/.

Comment: I've changed the class of `<select>` elements to `form-control-select2`, because the `select2` class is used by the plugin for some elements that are rendered in page.

Answer (score 0):

Put your select tag inside a form with an `id="submit"` as shown

```
<form class="" action="" method="post" id="submit">
```

and add a button below the 4 select tags with this attribute

```
onclick="return submit_form('form#submit')"
```

the button should be like this,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return submit_form('form#submit')">Submit</button>
```

In your jquery

```
  function submit_form (form_id) {
    $(form_id).find('select[name]').each(function (index, node) {
      if (node.value == 0) {
        var id = "select#" + node.id;
        $(id).addClass('errorType');
      }
    });
  }
```

This will search select tag with name as attribute, if found, it will get the value of the name and check of its empty or not. If found empty it will add new class that turns that select tag into a red border.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick. You just need to replace #yourButton with the actual ID you use.

```
$(document).on("click", "#yourButton", function() {
  $(".select2").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).removeClass("errorType");
    if ($(element).val() === "0") {
        $(element).addClass("errorType");
    }
  });
});
```